# jQuery copy other div element when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, copy, element

So I've got this tricky (at least for me) script to write/modify. You can see below how it looks right now:

HTML:

```
<div class="holder" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px">
    <input type=checkbox class="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
</div>
<div class="holder" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px">
    <input type=checkbox class="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
</div>
<div class="holder" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px">
    <input type=checkbox class="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
</div>
<div class="holder" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px; clear: right">
    <input type=checkbox class="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
</div>

<div class="number">
    0
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var increment2=1; 
        $('.checkbox').live('click', function() { 
        $('.number').html( '(' + increment2 + ')'); 
        increment2++; 
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P3zMu/13/

What needs to be done is that when you check on of the boxes the h2 content of the container should appear in the ul as li. If there are 3 boxes checked, than in the ul will be 3 li etc... when you uncheck the box it's ofcourse being removed from the ul.

I hope my explanation is making sens. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried?  Your code does not even have a `ul`.

Comment: there are no ul/li in your html code.

Comment: yeah, sorry, the previous version didn't save. now it's working.

Comment: Effort, my friend. Effort. I'm sure you will get an answer at some point, but you would be a lot happier tackling this (actually rather simple) problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made few minor changes to your html and implemented below code,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/P3zMu/24/) here

```
var increment2 = 1;

$('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    $('.number').html('(' + increment2 + ')');
    increment2++;

    var $div = $(this).parent('div').get(0);

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {        
        $('#selected_items').append('<li selected-item="' + $div.id + '_selected">' + $($div).find('h2').text() + '</li>');
    } else {
        $('#selected_items > li[selected-item^="' + $div.id + '"]').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something using the clone() method should work:

```
var increment2=1; 
    $('.checkbox').live('click', function() {  
    increment2++; 
    $('.number').append($(this).next().clone());
})
```

That will just append the next element after the checkbox (the h2 in this case) to the .number  element, but you get the idea.  In order for this to work correctly, you would need to put in different values instead of lorem ipsum for each, then check to see if they already exist/remove them on uncheck - didn't have time to write that up.